# Prove that if A & B are disjoint open sets then their intersection is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, analysis, compactness

Prove that if A & B are disjoint open sets then their intersection is compact. could anyone give me a hint on how to do this please?

**My trial**
their intersection will be the empty set which is closed, but I do not know how to justify that it is bounded even though I am convinced that it is bounded. could anyone help me in this please? is my trial correct?

Comment: Don't do it that way! Any singleton can cover the null set. So for any open cover $\mathcal U$ of $\emptyset$ [choose any one member from $\mathcal U$] we get a finite subcover that overs $\emptyset$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ being disjoint means that $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

$\emptyset$ is trivially compact since the collection $\emptyset$ (which is a finite subset of any cover of $\emptyset$) covers it.

This has nothing to do with $A$ and $B$ being open.

Comment: you mean the condition of being open is unnecessary here?

Comment: @hopefully: Correct. Nowhere in the above did we use openness.